# How to install TP-LINK TL-WR841ND router

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I bought a TP-LINK TL-WR841ND router, but it isn't supported by Linux.

Can someone help me to install it in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 2):

You don't install a router, you just plug it in to your LAN, and configure it.  Before installing the Router, make sure your PC is connected to the Internet through the broadband service successfully.

The default domain name of the TL-WR841ND 300Mbps Wireless N Router is http://tplinklogin.net, the default IP address is 192.168.0.1, and the default Subnet Mask is 255.255.255.0. These values can be changed as you desire.

To access the configuration utility, open a web-browser and type in the default domain name http://tplinklogin.net in the address field of the browser, or 192.168.0.1.  When the login window comes up, enter admin fro the username and password, and once in set it up according to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Linux driver available for your wifi router .

```
wget http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/software/TL-WR841N_WR841ND_v7_120201.zip
```

that command can download that. As I have seen in the TL official page in the notes area they have mentioned that it is suitable for both For `TL-WR841N & TL-WR841ND`. For more information : [TPLINK](http://www.tp-link.com/en/support/download/?model=TL-WR841N&version=V7)

Comment: That is not a driver, but firmware, depending on the routers firmware you may not need to upgrade.  Plus go with the latest firmware, because it addresses more bug fixes, and modifications.